# Join a third table on this query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join the third table `comment` in this query.  The complaint and comment table relate to the main table `queue` by `id` and `queue_id`.  The complaint and comment table have a couple of different columns.  This query brings in all the columns and the rows from `comment` but not `complaint`.

```
SELECT  t.*,complaint.*, `comment`.*
FROM    queue t
LEFT JOIN   complaint
on      complaint.queue_id = t.id AND t.state='open'
RIGHT JOIN  `comment`
on      `comment`.queue_id = t.id AND t.state='open'
ORDER BY date_sort DESC
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: please show sample data and the output you are getting and the expected output.

Comment: Provide sample data

Comment: Here is a basic structure of what Im working with. [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7e536

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Query

SELECT  t.* ,complaint.* , comment.* FROM queue t LEFT JOIN   complaint
on t.id=complaint.queue_id  AND t.state='open' LEFT JOIN  comment on t.id=comment.queue_id AND t.state='open' ORDER BY date_sort DESC

Answer (score 0):

Just use left join through out. Try this:

```
SELECT  t.*, complaint.*, `comment`.*
FROM    queue t
LEFT JOIN   complaint
on  complaint.queue_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN  `comment`
on `comment`.queue_id = t.id 
WHERE t.state='open'
ORDER BY date_sort DESC;
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for insights.

Comment: The query times out after 30 seconds.